# Add/link a Docker postgres database container to my existing Docker python container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a python application dockerized that works really fine and now I want to add a postgres database. I thought the best idea is to dockerize the database and link it with my python app, so my app can store data in it, but every time the container is built, i get the same error:

This is the error I get when trying to build container:

```
[23165 ms] Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
[23165 ms]     at Pte (c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1954:3572)
[23165 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[23165 ms]     at async rre (c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:3833)
[23166 ms]     at async Yf (c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:4775)
[23166 ms]     at async Dne (c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:12193)
[23166 ms]     at async Sne (c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:11934)
[23176 ms] Exit code 1
[23180 ms] Command failed: C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe 
--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\IT\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers-0.299.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder 
c:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote- 
containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-f9b48955-34b9-42ed- 
b7eb-f5c37f6b7fb61689235866772 --workspace-folder c:\Users\IT\Documents\gys_test -- 
workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label 
devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\IT\Documents\gys_test --id-label 
devcontainer.config_file=c:\Users\IT\Documents\gys_test\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json 
--log-level debug --log-format json --config 
c:\Users\IT\Documents\gys_test\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe 
loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true -- 
skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[23180 ms] Exit code 1
```

These are my files. All of them are stored in the same directory ".devcontainer/" in the main folder of the project:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.9
RUN pip3 install pytest black
```

**devcontainer.json** (current version of the file):

```
{
"name": "Test development env",
"dockerComposeFile": "./docker-compose.yml",
"service": "python-app",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
"settings": {
  "files.eol": "\n",
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/__pycache__": true,
    "**/.pytest_cache": true,
    "**/.venv": true,
    "**/*.egg-info": true
  },
  "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
  "python.testing.pytestPath": "/usr/local/bin/pytest",
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
  "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    ".vscode/",
    "**/site-packages/",
    "**/__pycache__/",
    "**/.pytest_cache/",
    "**/*.egg-info"
  ]
},
"extensions": [
  "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
  "mhutchie.git-graph"
],
"remoteUser": "vscode",
"containerUser": "vscode",
"runArgs": [
  "run",
  "--service-ports",
  "--rm",
  "python-app"
],
"overrideCommand": true, // get the same error with/out this line, no difference
"postCreateCommand": "pip install -U --force-reinstall -e ."
```

}

**docker-compose.yml**. (of course users/passwords/db are right in my original files, I hide them here)

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.8
    restart: unless-stopped //no difference with restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <user>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <password>
      POSTGRES_DB: <db>
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

pgadmin:
  image: dpage/pgadmin4
  restart: always
  environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: <email>
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: <password>
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  depends_on:
    - db

python-app:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  depends_on:
    - db
```

And these are the files I'm using to build only my python app that works well:

**Dockerfile**: same as before

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
"name": "Test development env",
"dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
"settings": {
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/__pycache__": true,
        "**/.pytest_cache": true,
        "**/.venv": true,
        "**/*.egg-info": true
    },
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "/usr/local/bin/pytest",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
        ".vscode/",
        "**/site-packages/",
        "**/__pycache__/",
        "**/.pytest_cache/",
        "**/*.egg-info"
    ],
},
"extensions": [
    "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
    "mhutchie.git-graph",
],
"remoteUser": "vscode",
"containerUser": "vscode",
"runArgs": [
    "--network=host",
],
"postCreateCommand": "pip install -U --force-reinstall -e ."
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I think I have something wrong in my files but I also think I'm probably missing something... in my VSCode I have the Dev Containers and Remote Cevelopment extensions installed, could be the problem any of them? How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance, regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryied this and worked. Kept my original devcontainer.json & Dockerfile files, and in the docker-compose.yml I put this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <my_user>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <my_pass>
      POSTGRES_DB: <my_db>
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```